# How to change text color in drop down menu for element that is created with append()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for something in JQuery that can change the color of the element based on the value. I have my drop down populated dynamically, before I append my value to drop down I have if statement that checks for the value, if value is equal to 1 I want to change the color of that element if not leave it as it is. Here is my code:

```
for(var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    if(myArray[i].idFour == '1'){
        $('#users').append('<option value='+myArray[i].idOne+'>'+myArray[i].idTwo+'</option>');
        $('#users option').css('color','red');
        }else{
            $('#users').append('<option value='+myArray[i].idOne+'>'+myArray[i].idTwo+'</option>');
        }
}
```

Code above is changing color for all elements starting at the top of the drop down all the way down to the element that actually should be in red. My question is why all elements before are in red? How I can get text color in red only for elements with value 1 from myArray[i].idFour? If anyone can help please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mottie mentioned, you better create a string and append it to DOM once:

```
var optionList = $();
for(var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    var option = '<option ';
    if(myArray[i].idFour == '1'){
        option += 'style="color:red" ';
    }
    option += 'value="'+myArray[i].idOne+'">'+myArray[i].idTwo+'</option>';
    optionList = optionList.add(option);
} 
$('#users').append(optionList);
```

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oz4uum4g/)

Comment: It would be better to build the options as a string, then append them to the DOM once.

Comment: What you mean by "build the options as a string"? Are they already built as a strings?

Comment: I mean something like `option += "<option ...>";` inside the loop, then after all the options are added then use `$('#users').append(option);`.

Comment: @AntonTemchenko nice update, but you can't use `option.css()` inside that loop now; you'll need to add the style, or class name in the string, like in @Danibix's answer.

Comment: @Mottie options are still jQuery elements. I am creating array of jQuery elements

Comment: Oh, oops, my mistake.... hmm, I don't think I've ever tried appending an array though.

Comment: @Mottie, I've updated again, because list of jQuery elements is creating another way: by `.add()`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add a class to option tag that you want color. So code will seem like this:

```
for(var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++){
  if(myArray[i].idFour == '1'){
    $('#users').append('<option class="redColor" value='+myArray[i].idOne+'>'+myArray[i].idTwo+'</option>');
  }
  else{
    $('#users').append('<option value='+myArray[i].idOne+'>'+myArray[i].idTwo+'</option>');
  }
}
```

And create a css class `.redColor` in your css stylesheet:

```
.redColor {
  color: red;
}
```